# Get more result from Github search

Tags: python, github

I'm creating a script that scrape raw urls for a search keyword from Github using [Github search](https://github.com/search). First all I can get is 100 page with 10 results per page. But then I begin to filter search by language. So I start getting 100*10*10 results.

```
def search(keyword):
    with open(keyword+".txt", "a") as f:
        base ="https://raw.githubusercontent.com"
        l = requests.get("https://github.com/search?q={}&type=Code&ref=searchresults".format(keyword))
        for language in re.findall('<a href="(.*?)".*?ter-item">',l.text):
            for page in range(1,100):
                req = requests.get(language + "&p={}".format(page))
                for url in  re.findall('a href="(.*?)" title', req.text):
                    raw = base + url.replace("/blob", "")
                    f.write(raw + '\n')  
                    print raw
```

Is there are a method to get more results?

**Edit:**

I already checked Github API. But When I try to search for code I have to specify the repository. That's why I'm scrapping the results.

```
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Must include at least one user, organization, or repository",
      "resource": "Search",
      "field": "q",
      "code": "invalid"
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean per-page? Have you looked at the GitHub API https://developer.github.com/v3/ (and specifically https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) at all, rather than scraping the website?

Comment: @TomDalton `the GitHub Search API provides up to 1,000 results for each search.`
Which I get by scraping. But I want to get more than that. For example when I search for `google` I found `60,711,493` results But I can only get `1,000` either by scraping or by using the API.

Comment: I thought you were getting 10 results per page scraped, not 1000? Your code seems to suggest that too. The way I read the API docs, that gives you 1000 *per request*, and then you can make further requests for pages for results 1001-2000, 2001-3000 etc.

Comment: Yes I get 10 results per page. and I get 100 page for every language(10 languages). So in total I get 10*10*100. But as I say I can't use github API since I'm not looking inside specific repo.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code doesn't imply you need a specific repo in the search params, tho it does say it's limited to 100 results per page rather than 10...

Comment: Yes indeed but I think you didn't view my edit to the question. When I try to search without a `repo` I get the result above.

Comment: @ChakerBenhamed: did you solve your problem? I encounter this same issue.